# Cannot install turtle-cli with npm install -g

Tags: android, linux, react-native, npm, expo

I develop an app with expo and because of react-native-sound module I need to build an apk for test my program, but I must build in local, so I tried to install turtle-cli but I have many error and I don't know-how to fix it.

`expo diagnostics` return:

```
  Expo CLI 3.17.18 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 5.5 Fedora 30 (Workstation Edition) 30 (Workstation Edition)
      Shell: 5.7.1 - /usr/bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.19.0 - /usr/bin/node
      npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~37.0.3 => 37.0.6 
      react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
      react-native: ^0.62.2 => 0.62.2 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 3.17.18
```

First I tried without sudo:

```
...
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/Osmonoz/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T10_00_56_580Z-debug.log
```

And there is the `sudo npm install -g turtle-cli` errors:

```
...
> dtrace-provider@0.8.8 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js

gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/10.19.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.5.10-100.fc30.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> iltorb@2.4.5 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/iltorb
> node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild

WARN install EACCES: permission denied, access '/root/.npm'
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/10.19.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/iltorb/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/iltorb/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.5.10-100.fc30.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/iltorb
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> sharp@0.24.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

ERR! sharp EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm'
info sharp Are you trying to install as a root or sudo user? Try again with the --unsafe-perm flag
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/10.19.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/sharp/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/sharp/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.5.10-100.fc30.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
...

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.24.1 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.24.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T09_48_07_424Z-debug.log
```

I hope someone know what I'm doing wrong,

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer, it's pretty simple, I just need to add `--unsafe-perm` flag to the command:

`sudo npm install -g turtle-cli --unsafe-perm`

It was written underneath the error..

```
info sharp Are you trying to install as a root or sudo user? Try again with the --unsafe-perm flag
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a unsuitable permissions on **usr** folder,
you might try to change writing permissions using **chmod** command .

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this, but it doesn't work, and isn't a good idea for safety.